# angular dropdown option value login data object for user roles in database

Tags: angularjs, json, forms, controller

So I am finding myself at a bit of a roadblock on taking grabbing a value from a dropdown option in angular for creating one of two specific user roles for my postgreSQL database.

I have many inputs (several exclusive to each dropdown) for creating users such as:
 1. username
 2. password
 3. email
etc...

all are easily passed into a user object within my angular controller using ng-model to reference them. What I am trying to achieve with my form is for each option of my select dropdown to log a specific value to the key of role within my user object so i can store that to a specific record within the field of 'role'.

HTML Snippit:

```
    <form name="createAccount" ng-submit="create(this)">
<select ng-model="showRole" class="form-control" ng-options="role.abbreviation as role.name for role in roles">
      <option value="">Choose One</option>
</select>

<div ng-switch="showRole">
    <div ng-switch-when="agt">
        <div>
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="createAccount.firstName">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="createAccount.lastName">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="email">E-mail</label>
            <input type="e-mail" ng-model="createAccount.email">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="company">Agency</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="createAccount.company">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="createAccount-username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="createAccount.username">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="createAccount-password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" ng-model="createAccount.password">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="createAccount-passwordConfirm">Password Confirm</label>
            <input type="password" ng-model="createAccount.passwordConfirm">
        </div>

    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="pmt">
        <div>
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="createAccount.firstName">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="createAccount.lastName">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="email">E-mail</label>
            <input type="e-mail" ng-model="createAccount.email">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="company">Venue</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="createAccount.company">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="createAccount-username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="createAccount.username">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="createAccount-password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" ng-model="createAccount.password">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="createAccount-passwordConfirm">Password Confirm</label>
            <input type="password" ng-model="createAccount.passwordConfirm">
        </div>

    </div>

    <div>
        <button>Create Account</button>
    </div>
```

and Angular Controller:

```
   (function(){
   var LoginController = function ($scope, $http ) {
$scope.pageID = "Login/Register Page";



$scope.create = (form) => {
  console.log('create form submitted');
  const user = {
    firstName: form.createAccount.firstName,
    lastName:  form.createAccount.lastName,
    email:     form.createAccount.email,
    company:   form.createAccount.company,
    username:  form.createAccount.username,
    password:  form.createAccount.password,

  }
  $http.post('/users/create', user)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
}

$scope.loginSubmitted = (form) => {
  console.log('login form submitted');
}

 $scope.roles = [{ abbreviation: 'agt', name: "Agent"},{abbreviation: 'pmt', name: "Promoter"}];
 this.setTab = function(setTab) {
   this.tab = setTab;
 };

 this.isSelected = function(checkTab) {
   return this.tab === checkTab;
 };

 this.notSelected = function(checkTab) {
   return !(this.isSelected(checkTab));
 };

 this.getTab = function() {
   return this.tab;
 };

 this.setIsDefault = function() {
   this.isDefault = true;
 };

 this.getIsDefault = function() {
   return this.isDefault;
 };
 }

  angular.module('avp')
  .controller('LoginController', LoginController);

LoginController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

 }())
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. I am kinda ashamed of the fact that I asked such a dumb question but it is event more satisfying to figure out the answer and answer my own question on here for the first time.

All I had to do was new property in user object with form.showRole. WHOOO Crazy!

Overthinking it FTW!